# Join 3 Distinct Tables in MySQL with no Common or Linked Column

Tags: mysql

I Have Three Distinct Tables in Mysql which have no column in common, I want to access one column from each table & show all of them combined elsewhere.

Table Details are

1. *Table_1* = screen, *Column Name* : S_Id
2. *Table_2* = Movie, *Column Name* : M_Code
3. *Table_3* = showdetails, *Column Name* : Show_Id

There are many more columns in each table but i have mentioned what i want to access.I Have tried the following code but this returns only column names as output & no column data is received in output.I am a beginner in Databases so please help me with this.

```
SELECT * FROM screen
JOIN movie ON movie.M_Code = screen.S_Id
JOIN showdetails ON showdetails.Show_Id = screen.S_Id;
```

Comment: My question is what will you achieve by combining these tables? what useful data will you gather?

Comment: The tables are not related to each other and you want all combinations, e.g. 3 screens, 50 movies, 100 showdetails = 150000 records?

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.  I would bet that there are columns in column, just with different names (a sign of poor database design).

Comment: @cs04iz1 i am trying to make "Movie Shows" which can be booked by customers later i am trying to do that by Linking Screen id of screen table , Movie Code of movie table & Show Id  of show details table (I may be wrong , But thats how i imagined it would work)

Comment: @Gaurav Kumar: What about my question; can you answer that, too?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you took the case wrongly .... i am not trying all combinations .....i just wanted to access one column each from 3 tables that can be shown in a table over a JSP page as it is.

Comment: But this is what you are telling us (quote: "have no column in common"). We all think that this makes no sense. Why would you want to combine records that are completely unrelated? So they must have columns in common. For instance Movie may have an ID and ShowDetails may have a MOVIE_ID, so both share a movie ID by which the records are related.

Answer (score 0):

you can create 3 individual select statements and link them on a hard coded artificial key

```
select a, b, c, d, e, f from (

  (select a, b, c, 1 as key from atable) aa
  inner join 
  (select d, e, f, 1 as key from btabke) bb
  on aa.key = bb.key
```

something along those lines

essentially, each select statement becomes its own table, selecting only those rows which you want to be linked to the other select based tables. The artificial key is a simple way of linking them together since you have no other means of doing so

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure I understand what you want to achieve. Are those tables somehow related to each other, e. g. has every movie a screen on which it is shown on? If so, you had to join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM screen JOIN movie ON movie.S_Id = screen.S_Id
```

Imagine your tables are like the following:

Screen

```
S_Id| name
-----------
1   | Main Screen
2   | Screen 2
3   | Little Screen
```

Table

```
M_Code| Name
-------------
1     | Find Nemo
2     | Odyssey in Space
3     | Lord of the Rings
```

Your join statement would join the IDs as they are, in this case Find Nemo to Main Screen, Odyssey in Space to Screen 2 and LOTR to the Little Screen. Thats probably not what you wanted to achieve, so you have to use or add a column which links those data rows to each other.

If you instead want to get every possible combination, you can use Constantins answer, but I think if you have many datasets this could get very slow. Instead you could retrieve all datasets of every table and combine only those which make sense in your program.